# Programming Error at / after deploying my Django project to Heroku but working well on local host

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, deployment

I have made all the migrations as recommended in previous posts.
I have also updated my settings.py as recommended inj previous posts.
here is my console message;

```
2022-10-13T22:36:21.289647+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
2022-10-13T22:36:21.289648+00:00 app[web.1]:     with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
2022-10-13T22:36:21.289648+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
2022-10-13T22:36:21.289648+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
2022-10-13T22:36:21.289648+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
2022-10-13T22:36:21.289648+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
2022-10-13T22:36:21.289648+00:00 app[web.1]: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "freelanceapp_post" does not exist
2022-10-13T22:36:21.289648+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...t"."slug", "freelanceapp_post"."category_id" FROM "freelance...
2022-10-13T22:36:21.289648+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                              ^
2022-10-13T22:36:21.289649+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-10-13T22:36:21.290265+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.23.15 - - [13/Oct/2022:22:36:21 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 196793 "https://dashboard.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2022-10-13T22:36:21.289879+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=victorkiprono.herokuapp.com request_id=b9f45047-6c65-44e5-975d-b0f71a4c023b fwd="105.161.25.118" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=133ms status=500 bytes=197110 protocol=https
```

Comment: is your db migrated & up to date? `python manage.py makemigrations` + `python manage.py migrate` .. `relation "freelanceapp_post" does not exist` means it's a db error. **Edit:** sorry I'm presuming your homepage uses db calls and isn't static

Comment: You say you've made migrations and updated settings.py, but have you _applied_ your migrations? You'll need to do that on Heroku, e.g. by running `heroku run python manage.py migrate`.

Comment: I already did the migrations at heroku console it it still does not work

Comment: @Nealium So what should I do for the homepage?

Comment: Should migrations be done before or after deploying?

Comment: @KipronoKirui Just migrate before & after deploying *(just to be safe)* ..and naw your homepage is fine

Answer (score 0):

It has finally worked. I ran this command;

```
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

And the output was as shown below:

> Operations to perform:
> Synchronize unmigrated apps: freelanceapp, messages, profiles, staticfiles
> Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
> Synchronizing apps without migrations:
> Creating tables...
> Creating table freelanceapp_post
> Creating table freelanceapp_category
> Creating table profiles_userprofile
> Running deferred SQL...
> Running migrations:
> No migrations to apply.

Thank you all for your responses.